# Tiled background for UITableViewCells whose height is not known in advance

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

My app has a grouped table view, and the cells use linen as their background, with no divider. The linen pattern repeats perfectly when tiled 150x150, but if cell 0 is 100 pixels tall, since the pattern starts again at pixel 0 in cell 1 it becomes noticeable, as the lines in the linen wouldn't match up. The linen ends where the table view ends, and so it needs to scroll with it too.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work more gracefully?

Comment: Did you use a 24bit/32bit PNG file as the linen image?

Comment: Don't know what bit it is, but yeah, it's a PNG file.

Comment: I asked because I've experienced a similar bug before. If you use 8bit PNGs, sometimes the image will shift like 1 pixels.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that obviously when the next cell starts, it's going to start at pixel 0. And the previous image is at pixel 100, not 150, which is the same as pixel 0. So it appears to jump, just like if you were tiling say, a gradient, and cut off the bottom third of it.

Comment: In that case you just needed a matching graphic. So what question are you really asking?

Comment: The graphic matches, when tiled. But in each cell, it's going to start again from pixel 0. So it's not going to match up. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: If the graphic matches, you won't have a problem. You need a matching graphic that is 100px in height. Otherwise you'll have to repaint every cell, depending on its position. I don't think it'll look good.

Comment: Every cell isn't 100px in height, that was an example. Every cell is a different height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `UIColor` to set your pattern background, you probably need to switch to putting in a `UIImageView`. Set the `frame` appropriately, but adjust the origin of the `bounds` to scroll the inner content.

So the cell at row 0 will have bounds with `origin.y = 0`. The cell at row n will have bounds with `origin.y = (n * [your cell height])%[your source texture height]`. In order to handle wraparound (eg, if your cell were meant to contain the final line of your source pattern at the top, then roll back onto the first line) you'll probably want to create a modified texture image that's `[cell height] + [source texture height] - 1` pixels tall and has the first portion of the texture repeating at the bottom.

Comment: The cell heights change though. There's no way to know in advance how big they will be. So i can't tell another cell 'start the image at this point', because it doesn't have a way of knowing what that point would be, without some code to ask every cell prior how tall it is, which when you get onto cell 100 can take a while.

Comment: Actually you can; in your subclass of `UITableViewCell` just implement a new `setFrame:` that uses the `origin.y` to set the background image `bounds`. Table views are subs of the scroll view that manage the cells within them manually but are still explicitly placing them within a large, continuous scroll area.